# How do GWT 2.1 data presentation widgets work in conjunction with MVP?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

The Data Presentation Widgets in GWT 2.1 seem to have it all sewn up: model, view **and** presenter. So how does all of this data presentation goodness fit in with MVP? For example; how might I associate presenter (aka Activity) instances with the nodes of a CellTree? And is that even something that I should be trying to do?

**EDIT (elaboration):**

Where does the TreeViewModel belong? Is it rightly part of the View, or part of the Presenter? And how does one obtain a reference to the ListDataModel for a sub-branch of the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to give your view a reference to your presenter, and vice versa.  If your CellTree needs access to your presenter, define a function like setPresenter in the CellTree.

Another solution would be to create EventHandlers that attach to your view, and then have your presenter listen for those events and respond by calling into the interface of your view.  Less coupled, more verbose.  I like to create generic interfaces for both my Presenter and my View to keep them totally separate but still avoid having to deal with EventHandlers.